# Why segmentation fault(core dumped)?

Tags: c++

Why am I getting a segmentation fault(core dumped) error?

I haven't tried much, I know the code works, but stepik shows these errors

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int maximum(int a, int b)
{
  return (a > b) ? a : b;
}

int knapSackValue(int capacity, int weight[], int value[], int x)
{
  int i, w;
  int Kn[x + 1][capacity + 1];
  for (i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
    for (w = 0; w <= capacity; w++) {
      if (i == 0 || w == 0)
        Kn[i][w] = 0;
      else if (weight[i - 1] <= w)
        Kn[i][w] =
            maximum(value[i - 1] + Kn[i - 1][w - weight[i - 1]], Kn[i - 1][w]);
      else
        Kn[i][w] = Kn[i - 1][w];
    }
  }
  return Kn[x][capacity];
}

int main()
{
  int x;
  cin >> x;
  int capacity;
  cin >> capacity;
  int value[x];
  int weight[x];
  for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    cin >> value[i];
    cin >> weight[i];
  }
  cout << knapSackValue(capacity, weight, value, x);
  return 0;
}
```

Write an algorithm that uses dynamic program to find a solution to the knapsack problem.
The input is the capacity of the knapsack then each row of the table of values and weights.

The output is the resulting maximum value of the items that can be put in the knapsack.
Sample Input 1:

```
11
1 1
6 2
18 5
22 6
28 7
```

Sample Output 1:

```
40
```

Comment: Have you tried it in a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Your code reads two integers, `x` and `capacity`, before starting to read the `value`/`weight` pairs.  However, your sample input file only contains one integer before those pairs.  So you end up reading 1 into `capacity`, 1 into `value[0]`, 6 into `weight[0]`, 2 into `value[1]`, 18 into `weight[1]`, and so on.  In particular, `weight[4]` never gets initialized at all.

So when `i=5` in `knapSackValue`, and you reference `Kn[i - 1][w - weight[i - 1]]`, then `weight[i - 1]` contains a garbage value, and `w - weight[i - 1]` is out of range as an index into `Kn[i - 1]`.

Either your code or your input file is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Doube-check your question, particularly the example data. E.g. `"Sample Input 1:"` looks suspicious (which may just be where the line-break falls on my screen).

The following declarations are not supported by the C++ Standard:

```
int value[x];
int weight[x];
```

The same applies to:

```
int Kn[x + 1][capacity + 1];
```

Why? *Variable Length Arrays* (VLAs) are not part of the C++ standard and are only offered as non-standard compiler extensions.

Further, you attempt to return `Kn` which is declared local to `knapSackValue()` and which ceases to exist after the function returns.

Depending on your answer to whether the `1` in `"Sample Input 1:"` is part of your data or it means what it says (e.g. this is Sample No. 1) I can comment further. Additionally See Nate Eldridge's answer if this data is really "Sample No. 1".